# What is the best way to get up to speed with PHP/Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I have built Web sites with Python/Django and desktop applications with Objective-C/Cocoa so programming is not something that I need to learn.  For someone in my situation, what is the best way (specific books or Web sites) to learn PHP and Javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For PHP, I recommend [the official tutorial](http://ie.php.net/tut.php), and then [the manual](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/index.php). PHP is well documented and user comments on doc pages are also very useful.

For JavaScript, I recommend [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101992/). The book teaches the language from the grounds up, and then goes through browser-specific matters like the DOM API.

[image: JavaScript: The Definitive Guide]

Comment: The php.net documentation coupled with the user contributed comments are pretty much all you need, anything else theres SO.

Comment: +1 for recommending Flanagan's book

Answer (score 1):

Ayman has recommended an excellent book and two good resources. Aside from that, PHP has a few gotchas that you'll pick up with experience.

Once comfortable with PHP and Javascript I'd recommend looking at some javascript libraries such as [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui) and looking at the source of one you like, then maybe take a look at something like the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) or [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) for PHP.

Comment: Don't forget about Prototype.  Its great for those who are really used to OOP.